# ajax is not working even though I pressed the button which is allocated for the function

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
     pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
     <!DOCTYPE html>
     <html>
     <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/style.css">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
     <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
 
     <title>회원가입</title>
     <style type="text/css">
     div{
    background-image: "../img/space.jpeg"
 
     }
     </style>
     <script  type="text/JavaScript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
    $("#ajax_idDuplicate").click(function(){
    // userID 변수에 id의 입력된 값을 가져오게 함
        var id = $("#id").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",  // GET or POST 전송방법 
            url: "../UserIdCheckServlet",  // 이쪽으로 보낸다(호출URL)
            data: {"id": id},  // userID 이름에 userID 데이터 값을 넣어서 보낸다
            success: function(result){  // 만약 성공적으로 수행되었다면 result로 값반환
                if(result == 1){  // id가 checkMessage인 것에 아래 텍스트 출력
                $('#checkMessage').html('사용할 수 있는 아이디입니다.');
                } else {
                    $('#checkMessage').html('사용할 수 없는 아이디입니다.');
                }
                // id 가 exampleModal인 모달함수 실행시켜서 모달 실행시키기 위해
                $('#checkModal').modal("show");
            },
            error: function(xhr,status,error){
                alert(error);
            }
        });
    });
     </script>
        
     </head>
     <body>
     <div id="join-box">
   <div>
   <a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/MainServlet"><img src="            
   <%=request.getContextPath()%>/img/joinForm/x_button.jpg" border="0" width="15" height="15" 
 align="right"></a>
   <br>
     <h2>회원가입</h2><br/>
     <span style="color: red;">${msg }</span>
     <form action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/JoinServlet" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="name" placeholder="이름" /><br>
        <input type="text" name="id" id="id" class="id" placeholder="아이디 입력" />
        &nbsp
        <!-- <button class="duplicate_check">중복확인</button> -->
        
        <!-- 부트스트랩 테스트 -->
        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
        <button type="button" value="중복확인" id="ajax_idDuplicate" class="social-signin" data-bs-toggle="modal"data-bs-target="#checkModal">
        중복확인
        </button>
        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="checkModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">아이디 중복 확인</h5>
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body" id="checkMessage">
              <!-- 적을 내용 (알람창) -->
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">닫기</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
 
        <!-- 부트스트랩 테스트 -->
        
        
        
        <input type="password" name="pw" placeholder="비밀번호 입력" /><br>
     연락처 : <br/><select name="phone1">
        <option value="010">010</option>
        <option value="011">011</option>
        <option value="016">016</option>
        <option value="018">018</option>
        <option value="019">019</option>
        </select>
        -<input type="text" class="phone" name="phone2">
        -<input type="text" class="phone" name="phone3"><br>
        성별 : 
        남자 <input type="radio" name="gender" value="man">
        여자 <input type="radio" name="gender" value="woman"><br>
     
   </div>
   <div>
        <input type="submit" name="signup_submit" value="회원가입" />
     </form>
     <br>
     <br>
     <a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/MainServlet"><img src="    <%=request.getContextPath()%>/img/home.png" border="0" width="30" height="30" align="center"></a>
     </body>
     </html>
```

I am trying to use AJAX, and I am struggling with a problem which I can't find anymore.
Even though I press the button which has id of `ajax_idDuplicate`, the function which I decided to activate through the button is not working.

and there is no error in a console window and on my web browser. Could you guys help me for a while?

Comment: Quick guess: when you execute your script, the target element for  `$("#ajax_idDuplicate")` is not yet loaded. Check https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ for how to fix that. And why on earth JSP in 2021?

Comment: @GyroGearless What's wrong with JSP? Sure, you could argue that JSP leads to undisciplined code, but the alternatives are far worse.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers. I could solve it by loading it.

Answer (score 0):

Dom needs to be loaded before you call your function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#ajax_idDuplicate").click(function(){
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I could solve the problem by using your solution. really thank you!!!

Comment: Once It was useful it would be nice mark as correct answer.